# Refine a query of nearby placemarks but MKPointOfInterestFilter is not working

Tags: ios, swift, filter, mapkit, core-location

I am trying to refine a query of nearby placemarks. So far, all queries return the exact same 25 results. In the example below you can see 2 attempts (each done separately but displayed together for simplicity) labled "attempt 1" and "attempt 2"

```
func requestNearbyLocations() {
        var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
        region.center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: self.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    
        let request = MKLocalPointsOfInterestRequest(center: region.center, radius: 10000.0)
        //attempt 1
        self.mapView.pointOfInterestFilter = .some(MKPointOfInterestFilter(including: []))
        self.mapView.pointOfInterestFilter = .some(MKPointOfInterestFilter(excluding: [.restaurant, .cafe]))
        //attempt 2
        let categories : [MKPointOfInterestCategory] = [.cafe, .restaurant]
        let filters = MKPointOfInterestFilter(excluding: categories)
        self.mapView.pointOfInterestFilter = .some(filters)
        
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.start { (response , error ) in
            
            guard let response = response else {
                return
            }
            print(response.mapItems)
            for item in response.mapItems {
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
                annotation.title = item.name
                annotation.subtitle = item.phoneNumber
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                }
                
            }
            
        }
    }
```

How can I get the search to only return restaurants and cafes? I'd like to then use this to build more refined searches.

For example, the above search returned the below as one of the 25 entries in DC. I notice there is no "category" so how can it filter on a field that isn't part of the query?:

```
<MKMapItem: 0x28052a490> {
    isCurrentLocation = 0;
    name = "National Cherry Blossom Festival";
    phoneNumber = "+1 (877) 442-5666";
    placemark = "National Cherry Blossom Festival, 2 15th St NW, Washington, DC  20024, United States @ <+38.88923000,-77.03530000> +/- 0.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+38.88923001,-77.03530000> radius 141.17', center:<+38.88923001,-77.03530000>, radius:141.17m)";
    timeZone = "America/New_York (EST) offset -18000";
```

Also, it always returns 25 results. Is there a way to increase the results?

Comment: I've tried inverting the includes/excludes and that doesn't change it.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the filter to the wrong object. Apply the filter to the *request*, not the map.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalpointsofinterestrequest/3564414-pointofinterestfilter

Comment: I tried that already. I didn't show above every iteration that I tested.

Comment: Well I assure you that it works if you do it right. I can only help with code that you show. I have shown working code here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/d4c84b61b9634f206cb1a5df73a8c16b6200820d/iOS14bookExamples/bk2ch21p761userLocationAndGeocoding/ch34p1024userLocationAndGeocoding/ViewController.swift

Answer (score -2):

You're setting the `pointOfInterestFilter` on the `mapView` when it should be set on the request.

```
request.pointOfInterestFilter = MKPointOfInterestFilter(excluding: [.restaurant, .cafe])
```

The `mapView` and the `request` are unrelated to each other, so setting the filters on one doesn't affect the other.

Comment: that request always returns nothing.